# Disabled all input text field of a class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with gravity form but gravity form is submitting all fields into database, some class have `style="display"none"` but still data going into db.
this is an example of my html dom

```
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
```

I want to disable all input elements which is in all class `gf_left_half` with `display :none`
like

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
```

I am looking for jquery solution.

**Updated**
I am applying like this on my real dom but it is disabling all input of `just_test` class including which not have `style display none`

```
    <li id="field_8_160" class="gfield gf_left_half just_test field_sublabel_below 
field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_8_160">
Cost per Person
</label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number">
<input name="input_160" id="input_8_160" type="text" value="2,860" class="small" aria-invalid="false" disabled="disabled">
</div>
</li>
```

applying like this:

```
jQuery('.just_test:hidden').each(function(index,elem){
  jQuery(elem).find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I want to disable input field, but only when gf_left_half is display none

Comment: No, it work. But you added `disabled="disabled"` to input in html

Comment: no, i did not added, i pasted final result after jquery run...

Comment: Check html you added in update

Comment: I trust you sir its work, but why it is not working at my form.

Comment: yes, it was not added by me in html...it was added by jquery code

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/pyq1Lfz5/ . The code add `disabled` to only `just_test` has `display:none`

Comment: I tested and works fine, I am calling this code on click event, may be its a problem?

Comment: Write `alert()` in your click event handler to detect event is fired. Also check console for error

Comment: its working, input are not disabled by default. event handler is working

Comment: Have you any error in console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: I think you have problem in selector. Create jsfiddle and add all of your html to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `.gf_left_half` and use `:hidden` filtering selected class to only hidden element.

```
$(".gf_left_half:hidden input").prop("disabled", true);
```

```js
$(".gf_left_half:hidden input").prop("disabled", true);
console.log($(".gf_left_half input:disabled").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:block">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
```

Also you can use `.filter()` to select element has `display: none`

```
$(".gf_left_half input").prop("disabled", function(){
  return $(this).parent().css("display") == "none";
});
```

```js
$(".gf_left_half input").prop("disabled", function(){
  return $(this).parent().css("display") == "none";
});
console.log($(".gf_left_half input:disabled").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:block">
  <input type="text" value="hh">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for help, please see my updated question..its not working for me.. :(

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.gf_left_half:hidden').each(function(index,elem){
  $(elem).find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:block">
    <input type="text" value="hh">
    </div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value="hh">
    </div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value="hh">
    </div>
<div class="gf_left_half" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value="hh">
    </div>
```

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.just_test:hidden').each(function(index,elem){
  $(elem).find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="field_8_160" class="gfield gf_left_half just_test field_sublabel_below 
field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_8_160">
Cost per Person
</label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number">
<input name="input_160" id="input_8_160" type="text" value="2,860" class="small" aria-invalid="false">
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_8_160" class="gfield gf_left_half just_test field_sublabel_below 
field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style="display:none">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_8_160">
Cost per Person
</label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number">
<input name="input_160" id="input_8_160" type="text" value="2,860" class="small" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
</li>
```

You are disabled all inputs by default that's why which is not working as you expected.

Comment: thank you for help, please see my updated question..its not working for me.. :(

Comment: its working here sir, but not at my form. I applied same code

Comment: Any error? Check is there any events or css affecting that element.